# Inserting meaningless phrase in sentences

Tags: grammar, linguistics

Consider the following sentences:

> - The solution to this differential equation, **you know**, must be correct.
> - He is usually, **you know**, very crazy.

What is such phenomenon (inserting meaningless phrase in a sentence) called?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is an example of a *filler phrase*, in this case a *parenthetical filler phrase* since it is located in the middle of a sentence. Perhaps the most infamous filler in BrE is *innit* (isn't it?):

> "I'm going down the shops, innit"

Dear reader, please avoid.

[Collins English Dictionary: you know](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/you-know)

[Oxford Living Dictionaries: innit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/innit)

Comment: Likewise, "like" and "awesome", favored by our American cousins. We Brits get by with utterances of "yer know" and the like. I get by, by issuing $5 fixed-penalty notices to miscreants who mangle our beloved language in this way, what? A nice little earner, as we say. And the next one, please!

Comment: @Peter I'm, like,  skint, innit?

Comment: Quite so, me ol' mucker!

Comment: @PeterPoint "Like" yes, "awesome" not so much. *Awesome* is generally a genuine interjection (when it's not an adjective). I mean, sometimes I'm all "Um, yeah. So...well. Y'know." And then my friend is like "Awesome." And I go "I know, right?" And a lot of those are fillers or speech disfluencies or verbal/vocal pauses, but not awesome. Amirite?

Comment: I definitely think 'innit' is being used to form a tag question, it's the same as 'don't we?' in this instance, and I wouldn't describe that as a 'filler phrase'

Comment: @Au101 The Oxford Dictionary gives both, so I decided to use it.

Comment: Yes, I think it's hard to draw a line between an all-purpose tag and a filler, but I think that example is more on the side of a tag question. The speaker almost certainly doesn't *want* an answer, but it does invite agreement from the listener. I don't mean the speaker is expecting them to say 'yes' or nod along, but the listener agrees, right? He's on the same page as the speaker, isn't he? If you see what I mean? :P

Comment: Whereas something more like, 'I'm going down the shops, innit', or 'I like bacon, innit' is much more of a filler

Comment: @Mike As clear as...mud, don't ya know.

Answer (score -2):

A "*no-op*" is a term that originated in computer science. I think it is becoming used more widely. A "*no-op*" is something that takes up space (in assembly code), but does nothing.

I've heard this metaphor used many times. But maybe I've only heard it from programmers? I'm not sure. Of course, the younger generation is a lot more computer literate these days. Anyway, the metaphor is perfect.

> The phrase "*like you know*" is a frequent no-op in conversational American English.

Here is the definition *www.dictionary.com*. Please see the 3rd definition
[no-op](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/no-op)

Comment: Can you point to some sources where _no-op_/_nop_ is used outside of programming? (I've never heard it used such myself.)

Comment: @wchargin The 3rd definition: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/no-op

Comment: The source for that entire entry, including the third sense, is copied verbatim (with attribution) [from _The Jargon File_](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/N/no-op.html), a.k.a. _The New Hacker's Dictionary_, a self-described "comprehensive compendium of hacker slang." I'm not sure that this qualifies as "outside of programming."

Comment: @wchargin I can agree of course slang but its always a good day to learn something new. Based on context that phrase is useful. The op can decide.